# Variables not changing from React setState simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a table of users in a workflow where each user has a different status based on which step they are in the workflow. For ease of the example, lets say there are 4 steps from 1-4.

Each user has a button on their table row that when clicked, opens up a modal that grabs their userId and current step as data values.

```
handleClick = (event) => {
    let step = event.target.dataset.step;
    let id = event.target.dataset.id;
    this.setState({ currentStep: step, userId: id, moveUserModal: true });
}
.........
<Modal
    isOpen={this.state.moveUserModal}
>
    <UserModal step={this.state.currentStep} userId={this.state.userId} close={this.close} />
</Modal>
```

And in the modal:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
}
```

the console log returns undefined for the two vars and f() for close. If moveUserModal is true, is there a reason that the other vars wouldnt already have a value the constructor can access?

Comment: try putting your `console.log` in the `render()` method of the modal. Constructor is not called when parent re-renders

Comment: also, you put a log in the `handleClick` to confirm that the values are being set correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing your UserModal from mouting from the beginning.

When your parent component is mounting, your UserModal is also mounting and the constructor is already called with undefined.

Maybe try with something like:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.moveUserModal} >
    this.state.moveUserModal && <UserModal step={this.state.currentStep} userId={this.state.userId} close={this.close} />
</Modal>
```

Comment: We totally had something like this elsewhere in the project and I missed it. Thanks!